# Not able to find ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed all the steps given , but cannot find the above package. Also checked all the packages but cannot find ros-kinetic.
I'm running Ubuntu 16.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257104/not-able-to-find-ros-kinetic-desktop-full/) by [Padam Sethia](https://answers.ros.org/users/29706/padam-sethia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS install instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) specifically state that only Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 are supported; you cannot install ROS through apt on 16.10.

I recommend that you switch to Ubuntu 16.04 (it's their long-term stable release anyway) or [install from source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-15**:
Indeed:

> ROS Kinetic **ONLY** supports [..] Xenial (Ubuntu **16.04**) [..] with debian packages

**Comment by [Padam Sethia](https://answers.ros.org/users/29706/padam-sethia/) on 2017-03-15**:
I tried installing from source , but its showing error .

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
```

to system dependencies:
rosconsole: No definition of [rosunit] for OS version [yakkety]

?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-15**:
If you have no real need to run 16.10, I **strongly** advise you install 16.04 and use the provided binaries. It will save you a lot of effort and (potential) frustration.

If you must build from source, you'll have to *override* the OS detection. See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables.